# Exception: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.AbstractSSTableSimpleWriter

Tags: java

i am getting this exception:
while running Java Program

```
 ByteBuffer uuid = ByteBuffer.wrap(decompose(entry.key));
 //           usersWriter.newRow(uuid);
```

if i comment `:usersWriter.newRow(uuid);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.AbstractSSTableSimpleWriter.addColumn(AbstractSSTableSimpleWriter.java:114)
```

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using / have on the classpath?